# Capybara ambiguous match - should have_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Capybara and Rspec in a Rails app, and I keep failing some of my tests with this message :

```rb
Failure/Error: it { should have_content('error') }
Capybara::Ambiguous:
  Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "/html"
```

And that's kind of logical, because in my test, my app should render two messages with the 'error' content.

```rb
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <%= t('the_form_contains') %>
      <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, t('error')) %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li>* <%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here my application layout :

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="offset2 span8 offset2">
          <% flash.each do |key,value| %>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you know a way (like an option), to make it pass ?

**EDIT**

I used `save_and_open_page` and I didn't found any additional `html` tag, neither error messages outside the page. But when I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` then it works. Must I really have `<!DOCTYPE html>` and an opening `<html>` tag ? Can I delete `<!DOCTYPE html>` without consequences ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Le Troquet</title>
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body>
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
<!-- There is no html tag here -->
     .
     .
     .
     .
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the problem is that you either:

1. have two `<html>` tags in your page, or possibly
2. the "error" text appears *outside* the `<html></html>` tags.

See this discussion: [Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "/html"](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/881).

Comment: Strange, I don't have two `html` tags nor 'error' that appears outside the `html` tags...

Comment: What version of capybara are you using?

Comment: And what does your layout look like? Also, try adding a `save_and_open_page` in your spec to see what the HTML actually looks like.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found a way to circumvent the problem ;-)

Comment: You must have two HTML tags. That's exactly what the error message is saying.

Comment: Thanks @shioyama ! I have indeed two `html` tags, but the first one is `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Can I delete this tag without later being annoyed ?

Comment: The first is a doctype, not a html tag. That scenario is specifically mentioned in the link listed in the answer.

Comment: Those are different tags, so that doesn't sound like the source of the problem. see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp can you just post your layouts/application.erb.html ?

Comment: or try inserting a `save_and_open_page` in your spec to see the actual html, see: http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/ever-heard-of-capybaras-save_and_open_page-method/

Comment: I updated my post to make the application layout appear. But the `save_and_open_page` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, is it possible you have any html tag in your other partials? And what happened when you put `save_and_open_page` in your spec? Did it give you an error, or just do nothing?

Comment: Hi, I succeed to use `save_and_open_page` and I have neither of both problems... So I'm still stucked and I think my `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the cause.

Answer (score 4):

Check for elements outside of the closing `</html>` tag.  In my case (HAML), I had a javascript tag that was improperly indented

```
%html
  ...
:javascript
```

FIX

```
%html
  ...
  :javascript
    ...
```

Indenting the :javascript so it was contained within the html tag solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

OK, I understand the problem. When I use `should have_content`, Capybara search in the whole layout the content. But it finds two `html` tags, that make it fails, because it doesn't know which is the right one. And why is there two `html` tags ? Because Capybara doesn't ignore the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I solved my problem, but it's more of a bypass. Instead of searching a content, I made Capybara search for the 'error' div, that contains the 'error' messages. Thereby, it doesn't have to search the whole application layout, and it doesn't get stucked with the two `html` tags.

So I just had to replace `it { should have_content('error') }` by `it { should have_selector('div', text: 'error') }`, and it worked.

Comment: I don't believe that is the correct syntax for `have_selector` -- I think it's ignoring the 'error' you have there. Shouldn't it be: `have_selector('div', :text => 'error')`?

Comment: Yes, it seems so... But I'm in the middle of [something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977371/submit-button-helper-with-i18n-t/16977624?noredirect=1#16977624) else right now, that gives me so much rspec failing messages, that I will correct that later...

Comment: General piece of advice: you should take one problem at a time, and not just try to get your tests to pass without understanding what's actually happening. In the end it will just make things harder for you.

Comment: I agree, circumventing the error is not fixing it. If someone does have an answer for the actual question asked that would be great please. Thanks

Comment: Ever figure this out?