# Submit button helper with I18n.t

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I want to write a helper for a submit button, that takes in account the action (create or update) to get the right translation. Here they are :

```rb
fr: 
  submit:
    create:
      user: "Créer mon compte"
      product: "Déposer l'objet"
      session: "Se connecter"
    update:
      user: "Mettre à jour mon compte"
      product: "Modifier l'objet"
```

I tried this :

```rb
def submit_button(model)
  if model == nil
    I18n.t('submit.create.%{model}')
  else
    I18n.t('submit.update.%{model}')
  end
end
```

But it didn't worked and rspec send me that :

```rb
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find button ...
```

I know that's a syntactical problem, but I don't find how to make this work...

Comment: Define `doesn't work`, please )

Answer (score 16):

You don't need a helper for that, you can achieve it with plain rails. The only thing you need is to properly order your I18n YAML

```
fr:
  helpers:
    submit:
      # This will be the default ones, will take effect if no other
      # are specifically defined for the models.
      create: "Créer %{model}"
      update: "Modifier %{model}"

      # Those will however take effect for all the other models below
      # for which we define a specific label.
      user:
        create: "Créer mon compte"
        update: "Mettre à jour mon compte"
      product:
        create: "Déposer l'objet"
        update: "Modifier l'objet"
      session:
        create: "Se connecter"
```

After that, you only need to define your submit button like this:

```
<%= f.submit class: 'any class you want to apply' %>
```

Rails will take the label you need for the button.

You can see some more info about it [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/02/rails-3-i18n-changes/)

Answer (score 0):

```
def submit_button(model)
  if model == nil
    I18n.t("submit.create.#{model}")
  else
    I18n.t("submit.update.#{model}")
  end
end
```

The %{} is used in en.yml file when you send a local variable from helper or view.

Comment: Oops, when I run the server, the view renders a `translation missing: fr.submit.create.#{model}` button..

Comment: Change `'` to `"` in strings

Comment: Try `def submit_button(model)
  if model == nil
    I18n.t("#{model}", :scope => 'submit.create')
  else
    I18n.t("#{model}", :scope => 'submit.update')
  end
end`.

Comment: I tried but I still get the `translation missing: fr.submit.create.#{model}` button...

Answer (score 0):

You need the name of the model not the model object itself.

Try the following:

```
def submit_button(model)
  model_name = model.class.name.underscore
  if model.new_record?
    I18n.t("submit.create.#{model_name}")
  else
    I18n.t("submit.update.#{model_name}")
  end
end
```

`model` must not be nil in a form.

Comment: But I want to do a unique helper for every model I have. Can't I do that ?
And I think `model` can, and is, nil in a `new` form...

Comment: `model` cannot be nil in a new form, how do you call submit_button? Normally in the new action for the controller you create a new model which is used in the form. With my solution you have a unique translation for every model. By the way its better to call this method submit_button_translation because its provides only the translation and not the button.