# How do I use custom I18n label for submit button with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm using standard Rails forms in my view:

```ruby
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email_label %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :class => "form-control" %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_label %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control" %></div>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div class="checkbox"><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
    <% end -%>

    <div>
      <!--<%= f.submit  :class => "btn btn-default" %>-->
      <%= f.submit  I18n.t("helpers.label.user.sign_in"),  :class => "btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Two questions:  1) The API guide docs at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html seem pretty out of date.  The section on localized views begins with:

> Rails 2.3 introduces another convenient localization feature:
>   localized views (templates).

So I'm not sure how much to trust them, and the two other standard locations http://ruby-i18n.org/wiki  and https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n  don't really address my issue:

It's a little more complicated because I'm trying to do this in a Devise view.  Which means that the form_for is referring to a User model, even thought the controller is a Sessions controller.  So User.create which will work if I use the style here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit

```yaml
fr:
  helpers:
    user:
      submit:
        create: "Inscription %{model}"
        update: "Confirmer les modifications à %{model}"
```

with out including any text in the submit line

```ruby
<%= f.submit %>
```

But this would affect Create User everywhere, and I only really want to customize the New Session Button with the equivalent of Sign In.
Se me connecter

So I'm hacking it with

```
fr-CA:
  helpers:
    select:
      prompt: Veuillez sélectionner
    submit:
      create: Créer un %{model}
      submit: Enregistrer ce %{model}
      update: Modifier ce %{model}
      sign_in: Se me connecter
      sign_up: Inscription
    label:
      user:
        email_label: Courriel
        password_label: Mot de passe
        remember_me: Mémoriser mes infos
        submit: Se me connecter
        sign_in: Se me connecter
        sign_up: Inscription
```

And using

```
<%= f.submit  I18n.t("helpers.label.user.sign_in"),  :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

But this feels wrong, and also not robust, though it certainly enables easier Cucumber testing.

Any recommendations here?  And can anyone comment on whether the I18n community for Rails is still active?  Or are people using a different solution?  I've considering trying to go with SimpleForm gem and it's I18n features.

Comment: Maybe you could try `<%= l f.submit helpers.label.user.sign_in,  :class => "btn btn-default" %>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but the order of the keys is what important here:

```
fr:
  helpers:
    submit:
      user:
        create: "Inscription %{model}"
        update: "Confirmer les modifications à %{model}"
```

Note that `submit` goes first and *then* you should list your resources — `user`, `post`, `whatever`.

See the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18255633) for more details.

Comment: The OP did switch the model/submit keys in their example, but this doesn't really answer the question. This solution will still change the submit button text on every devise form associated with `User` (which includes sign up, sign in, reset password, etc.). The OP asked how to change it per-controller.